# How to protect against attack against a domain name?

Tags: security

A friend has a domain name which redirects to another through the domain registrar control panel. A few hours ago the server hugely slows down. When he removes the redirection server runs normally.

Is it frequent that a domain name is targeted ? The domain name is rather nice is it possible that some guys try to get it abandon ? What to do in that case ?

note: server is windows 2008 OS

Comment: Honestly you have provided minimal detail to "problem" that should be directed to the System Administrator of the server in question. There's absolutely no way we can pinpoint the issue without immensely more detail, and it sounds like you do not have the access necessary to provide those details. This site is for System Administrators only, per the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq), please see it for additional details.

Comment: The system Administrator is my Friend who rented a dedicated server. He's quite novice but do you remember yourself when you was a young student knowing nothing ? Why do you think I'm asking the question here if he would already know the answer. The reason I ask for him is precisely he thinks he would just be baffled by so called "professionals".

Comment: I think you're still misunderstanding. This site is for professionals, not for users to ask them questions, but for them to ask each other questions. To directly answer your questions, no, what you have described is incredibly infrequent. If I was to venture a guess, the redirecting server is misconfigured as an open proxy or something similar. Start by looking over the logs, see what they point to, ask questions based on that.

Answer (score 1):

There is just generally a lot of stupid people doing a lot of stupid things across the Internet. Usually, it's nothing personal to any particular person, domain name or anything else.

If the "attacking" IP addresses are visible across the server logs, then those attacks may be put under control by just blocking them from the server either at the server application, firewall or networking routing level. That may be a better alternative rather than pulling the other domain name off-line from the existing configuration.

Comment: What about DDOS attack ? You cannot manage only IP addresses.

Comment: DDOS is a broad term that span across multiple methods, but most (unless it is a inside-type job) will require the remote party to be able to get to you, so IP address are usually involved.